# Catching NotFound (404) and TimeOut (504) Django application exceptions in uWSGI + nginx setup

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I want to know how will I catch **NotFound** and **TimeOut** exceptions in the views.py in my Django application, setup using uWSGI + nginx. I tried this:

```
def sample(request):
    try:
        ...
        return HttpResponse("OK")
    except Exception, ex:
        return HttpResponse("%s - %s" % (type(ex), ex.message))
```

But I am still getting this html template response returned by nginx:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
      <center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
      <hr><center>nginx/1.6.2</center>
   </body>
</html>
```

When I am sending a request like this:

```
response = requests.get(test_url).content
```

I'm sure that the request that I am sending encounters a timeout exception.
How should I do this? Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Comment: No, it's your app that is generating a timeout. Now maybe that is caused by waiting too long for the remote API, but it is not the remote call that generates the timeout exception.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Alright, understood, and that's what I meant as well. Apologies for the confusion. But still, my question is how to catch it in the application? thanks again!

Comment: You shouldn't setup a global try/catch for making a request out to another server. You should have the try/catch around the individual calls to the other servers and handle the exception cases there. If you simply want to see the error information, you should be able to get that from your logger.

Comment: Thanks schillingt. But how will catch the timeout exception? Can you show an example snippet? thanks again!